# How to pass specific delegate to UIApplicationMain

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using next line to instantiate my application on iOS and everything works fine, expect that I don't know how to pass parameters to instantiate `MyAppDelegate`.

```
UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MyAppDelegate class]));
```

Is it possible to pass a specific instance of `MyAppDelegate` to `UIApplicationMain` or to specify how to construct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIApplicationMain):

```
int UIApplicationMain ( int argc, char * _Nonnull argv[], NSString *principalClassName, NSString *delegateClassName );
```

> delegateClassName
>
> The name of the class from which the application delegate is
>   instantiated. If principalClassName designates a subclass of
>   UIApplication, you may designate the subclass as the delegate; the
>   subclass instance receives the application-delegate messages. Specify
>   nil if you load the delegate object from your application’s main nib
>   file.

With `UIApplicationMain`, you tell iOS the name of the delegate class. Your app delegate is responsible for managing the high-level interactions between the system and your code.

**So, to answer your question - No, we do/can not pass specific instance of `AppDelegate` in `UIApplicationMain`. In fact, this is the entry point of application and nothing has been instantiated/loaded by far.**

I would also advise you to take a look at this [nice blog](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/06/app-launch-sequence-ios/) discussing the iOS app launch cycle.